# error: can't find a register in class ‘GENERAL_REGS’ while reloading ‘asm’

Tags: c, inline-assembly

```
__asm__ (       
    "loop:\n\t"
    "movl   $1,%3\n\t"
    "movl   $0, %6\n"
    "start:\n\t"

    "movl   (%1,%3,4),%4\n\t"       
    "movl   -4(%1, %3, 4), %5\n\t"  
    "cmpl   %4, %5\n\t"         
    "jle    next\n\t"

    "xchgl  %4, %5\n\t"     
    "movl   %4, (%1, %3, 4)\n\t"    
    "movl   %5, -4(%1, %3, 4)\n\t"  
    "movl   $1, %6\n"

    "next:\n\t"
    "incl   %3\n\t" 

    "cmpl   %3, %2\n\t" 
    "jge    start\n\t"  

    "cmpl   $0, %6\n\t"
    "je end\n\t"

    "jmp    loop\n" 
    "end:    \n\t"


:"=r"(input_array)
:"r"(input_array), "r"(size-1), "r"(1), "r"(0), "r"(0), "r"(0)

);
```

I get:

> error: can't find a register in class ‘GENERAL_REGS’ while reloading ‘asm’ error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remember that these machines have a limited number of registers. And its possible to actually run out - that's what the error you're getting is telling you.

On x86, there are only 8 general-purpose registers. `esp` is reserved for the stack pointer. `ebp` is probably in use as a base-pointer. So that leaves only 6.

However, your inline assembly snippet appears to want 7 registers? You don't have enough of them.

So the solution is that you will need to use fewer registers. Put some of the parameters in memory or change the algorithm...